# import layered pdf to inkscape

Tags: inkscape, pdf

I imported a layered PDF to Inkscape and edited that. after saving as again to PDF, my file is not a layered one. how can I edit a layered PDF file and export it as a  layered file?

Comment: Can I ask why you need layers in a PDF?  It shouldn't really matter. PDF is a format generally intended for publishing, not for re-editing. Perhaps you should change your work flow. Save your artwork as an Inkscape SVG. Any layers will be preserved. Use that file as the original (for future edits). Use PDF for export only.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I buy sewing patterns, every pattern has several size. every size is in one layer. I import my layered sewing pattern in Inkscape and then edit the sewing pattern and then save as in pdf for printing but my result is not a layered pattern. in fact, my purpose  is printing

Comment: OK, then changing the workflow as I commented could work for you. Save your edited SVG.  When you need to print, hide the layers you don't need, export as PDF, print it. Repeat for other sizes you want to print. Alternatively it might even be possible to just print directly from Inkscape and dispense with the PDF step entirely.

Comment: thanks but I opened the layer part in inkscape to hide unwanted played then I saw so many layers. every text and feature was had been a layer

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape doesn't support "optional content groups", which is the official name for PDF layers.

There is a [feature request on the official bug-tracker](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/3304), but it's kinda old and there hasn't been much activity. Presumably because it seems to be a pretty obscure feature, and Cairo, the library used for PDF export, which doesn't seem to support this either, would probably need to implement it first.

Apparently, [Scribus](https://www.scribus.net/) *does* support it, however, so you may be able to import your work – saved as Inkscape SVG – into Scribus and export it as PDF with layers.